# SSIS OLE DB Destination Editor - Create New Table not an option?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, oledbconnection, ssis-2017

I am trying to have upload a CSV file to my SQL Server via SSIS. Previously- like a few months ago- I was able to click 'New' on the destination editor to create a generic table based on the imported data. Is that option no longer available for some reason? I updated everything and made sure my credentials are correct and that I have read/write access but can't seem to get anything working. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT.

My screen used to look like this :

[image: OLD DB Destination Editor with 'New' table option]

But now it looks like this :

[image: OLE DEB Destination Editor with no new button]

Comment: @mlf it may be something related to the connector

Comment: @TalhaTayyab I'm still having the same issue, regardless of the data access mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue previously. The reason was that the `TargetServerVersion` was not set correctly. Make sure that this property is set to the same version of the SQL Server instance you are using.

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project?](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)